# Получить данные с usb устройства java

Tags: java, usb, wireshark

Вечер добрый, есть несколько устройств, которые проводят измерения и передают данные на пк (у каждого прибора своя программа).
Необходимо с помощью java, получить определенные параметры каждого прибора. Через wireshark смотрю пакеты, там есть request'ы и response'ы. Далее я моделирую request используя библиотеку (usb4java-javax) но, не могу получить response.
Вопрос реально ли это сделать? (получить данные с прибора, в виде объекта и далее с ним работать) Любые идеи приветствуются.

Comment: конечно реально. Правда я такое делал на python